# Local fork not fetching merge commit after pull request has been accepted?

Tags: git, github

I've forked a repository from github, made some changes in a local branch, submitted a pull request, and the request has been accepted. Now the repository I've forked from looks like this:
`... -> (commit)                       (merge_my_fix_commit [master])
                -> (my_fix_commit) ->`

where `my_fix_commit` is the commit I've submitted in my pull request, and `merge_my_fix_commit` is the merge commit made by the author.

The problem is that my fork's history remains exactly as before the pull request has been accepted:
`... -> (commit) -> (my_fix_commit)`

Making `git fetch --all` doesn't fetch the `merge_my_fix_commit`. Is this supposed to be like this? What should I do to make my fork's history look exactly like the original repo?

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behavior, your fork should not be updated. Pull requests are applied to the upstream repos, not to the forks.

What you can do is to add second remote to your repo, named, for example, `upstream`, pointing to the original repo (`git remote add upstream https://github.com/<original_user>/<repo>.git`). Fetch it (`git fetch upstream` or just `git fetch --all`) and re-push changes to your fork. The process is described in details [here](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/) and [here](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/).

Comment: I already have the original repo added as a remote. I actually did this before I added my github fork as a remote. Anyway, making `git fetch --all` prints: `Fetching origin... Fetching myfork...` but still no sign of the merge commit.

Comment: @Monfico, how do you view the repo? E.g. you should use `gitk --all`, not just `gitk` to see the changes, you haven't applied yet. Also, you can try to directly merge new commit in your local master with `git checkout master && git merge --ff-only upstream/master`, what is the result?